# Seeking free stereo paired .tiff image files

Tags: data-request

I'm somewhat new to GIS and am exploring creating DEM's from stereo paired images using [s2p](https://github.com/centreborelli/s2p). I've searched high and low for a source for stereo paired tiff files but I haven't had any luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the dataset from [A New Stereo Benchmarking Dataset for Satellite Images](https://deepai.org/publication/a-new-stereo-benchmarking-dataset-for-satellite-images) would be useful:

https://engineering.purdue.edu/RVL/Database/SatStereo/index.html